# Check for invalid inputs on ngIF Angular 11

Tags: angular, typescript

The code

.ts

```
buildForm() {
    this.commentForm = this.fb.group({
      name: [
        '',
        [
          Validators.required,
          Validators.minLength(2),
          Validators.maxLength(25),
        ],
      ],
      comment: ['', [Validators.required]],
    });
```

.html

```
<div fxFlex *ngIf="commentForm.value.name && commentForm.value.comment">
      <mat-list fxFlex>
        <div matLine><span>{{ commentForm.value.comment }}</span></div>
        <div matLine><span><b>{{ commentForm.value.name }}</b></span></div>
      </mat-list>
```

**The Context**: I got a required validator working writen in the .ts file for both the "name" and "comment" however the name has another validator attached to it which is check if the name has 3 or more characters

**The issue**: I got the code (above) mostly working that the div is hidden when the name and comment is empty however once the user types in the name of 2 characters or less, the div shows up -- I know I am missing a conditional here but Angular is fairly new to me so I dont know how to check for invalid inputs on an ngIf statement or is there something else that needs to be done for it (write a function then attached it on the template)?

**What I have tried**: I have tried putting "commentForm.value.invalid", "commentForm.value.name.invalid" & "commentForm.invalid" as part of the conditionals but no good.

Kindly help

Comment: something like: `commentForm.get('name').touched && commentForm.get('name').errors?.required`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could show the relevant error messages as below.

```
<div fxFlex *ngIf="commentForm.controls['name'].invalid && (commentForm.controls['name'].dirty || commentForm.controls['name'].touched)">
  <mat-list fxFlex>
    <div matLine *ngIf="commentForm.controls['name'].errors.required">
        Required error message here
    </div>
    <div matLine *ngIf="commentForm.controls['name'].errors.minLength">
        Min length error message here
    </div>
    <div matLine *ngIf="commentForm.controls['name'].errors.maxLength">
        Max length error message here
    </div>
  </mat-list>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, initially it did not work but I played around a bit with it and adjusted some values (ie making "commentForm......invalid to valid") and that did the trick